# Ensure GSI isn't duplicated in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB table currently has the PK, SK and a GSI called "EmailIndex".

The idea behind this is that when users create their account, the username will be set as the PK and the email would be set as the EmailIndex GSI.

This should let me allow the user to login with either the username or the email.

Is it possible to reliably ensure there is no duplicated EmailIndex record? If for example, two different people enter the exact same email at the exact same time with different usernames, how can I ensure both users don't end up creating a record with the same GSI?

Right now I'm under the assumption that this isn't actually possible with DynamoDB. In which case, what would be the acceptable and recommended approach of allowing username or email logins instead of mandating one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to guarantee unique values on a GSI. What I've done in the past to solve this is to have two records for the user, one with the data you have today, and one that is keyed on the email address. When doing a `Put` operation you can use a transaction to be sure both records succeed. You can still put the email in the GSI on the main record and use that for querying, or use the second record instead, and duplicate the data (which is what the GSI would do if you have the projection set to `ALL`).

Comment: Okay that's a good idea. So effectively instead of using the GSI we can just literally duplicate the record and change the hash key. This way I'd also have to do a transaction for the updates to to ensure parity between both the records when the user's account updates? Perhaps I could have three records. One for the username and password. One for the email, username and password. One for the user's actual account statistics using the username as the hash key. That way I'd only have to update the single statistic entry for all operations other than email/username updates. Would that work?

Comment: That may be a good idea. It depends a little on the frequency of expected updates. Ideally you want to isolate stable data (i.e. data that doesn't change much, if at all) from volatile data (i.e. data that changes frequently). This allows you to reduce the cost of updates. Remember, reads are a lot cheaper, and you can do a batch get if you want/need to get multiple records at once.

Comment: Just what I was thinking with isolating the account stats that change frequently from the username/email/password which is infrequent. Your answer is a great solution. Thank you, Jason!